# InfoPath form status stuck on "Installing"

Tags: infopath, 2007, solution-package

I have followed many of the recommended practices to install an InfoPath form that needs Administrative approval ([see this link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZMvYQ9P1loU&feature=related)). However, I am still unable to see the form finally complete it's propagation across my 2 web front ends. It is stuck in the "installing" status.

Additionally, I've done this via the command line ([see this link](http://walisystems.com/articles/SPS/publishusingcmdline/publishing_infopath_web_form_usi.htm)) ran the execadmsvcjobs command without any success.

I don't even see a timer job for the solution deployment. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to try, restart the timer service, then re-run the execadmsvcjobs operation from stsadm. You could also try removing the form and re-adding it after you reset the service. Also, check to make sure all of your servers are communicating properly with SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Is the server environment up to date on patches?  There was an InfoPath patch that came out last year that fixed some substantial performance issues with InfoPath and Forms Server.  I was working with some rather substantial forms at the time and the same form that would take 20 minutes to publish (via Admin approved forms path) before the patch would publish in 2-3 minutes after the patch.

Another tip, I found it RDP into the server and publish the forms with a browser connection from the server versus my local machine.

Comment: it was up to date. I'll try the RDP publish method next time I publish the form.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a workflow based InfoPath form by any chance? If so then it is most likely because the 'Alternate Access Path' has not been left blank when publishing the form.

Take a look here - [Workflow InfoPath forms stuck on "Installing" issue fix](http://juanlarios.blogspot.com/2008/01/workflow-infopath-forms-stuck-on.html)

Hope this helps,

Cheers

Alex